# Looping over multiple worksheets and finding the last blank cell and putting the max date header & formula from the range L:AD

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and trying to automate one of my repetitive tasks. I have multiple sheets in a workbook and the range from L upto a dynamic number of columns ( I say dynamic number of columns because for some sheets I have 2 columns and for some I have 14 columns) I have various dates. I need to go to the last blank cell, give the column header as "max date" and find out the max date from  the range of dates

I have tried this script myself but getting errors

```
Worksheets(1).Activate
Dim singlesheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each singlesheet In Worksheets
    singlesheet(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))).Rows.Count
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "Max date"
Next singlesheet
```

I get a Run time error 438

> Object does not support this property or method

Comment: On which line do you get the error ? `singlesheet(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))).Rows.Count` ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to write down "Max Date" in the header row, at the right column of every sheet, you can use something like the code below.

As mentioned in **SO** many times, you should stay away from using `Activate` , `ActiveCell` and `Select`.

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub MaxDateSheets()

Dim SingleSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastCell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each SingleSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With SingleSheet
        ' Use Find function to get the last column in sheet
        Set LastCell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=.Cells(1), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then
            LastCol = LastCell.Column
        Else
            MsgBox "Error! worksheet is empty", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If

        .Cells(1, LastCol).Value = "Max date" ' write "Max Date" in the header of the right column
    End With
Next SingleSheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. getting an error on that line..i will try this code

Comment: @Stanley on what line of my code do you get an error ?

Comment: the code does not work.  Instead of populating "Max date" in the last blank column it is giving an error message "Error .worksheet is empty"

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
Sub fnd_max()

Dim singlesheet As Worksheet

For Each singlesheet In Worksheets

    lr = LastRow(singlesheet)
    lc = LastCol(singlesheet)

    With singlesheet
    If lc > 0 And lr > 0 Then
        singlesheet.Activate
        .Cells(1, lc + 1).Value = "Max Header"
        .Cells(2, lc + 1).formula = "=MAX(" & .Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(2, lc)).Address(0, 0) & ")"
        .Cells(2, lc + 1).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(Cells(2, lc + 1), Cells(lr, lc + 1))
    End If
    End With

Next

End Sub

Function LastRow(Sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = Sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=Sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(Sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = Sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=Sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```